# How can I run a python script on Google Cloud project or AWS instances without manually firing them up?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I have some python scripts that require a good machine. Instead of starting instances manually on GCP or AWS, then making sure all python libraries are installed, can I do it through python for example so that the instance is on only for the time needed to run the script?

Answer (score 1):

If you're in AWS you could just create Lambda functions for your scripts and set those on a timer via Lambda or use Cloudwatch to trigger them.

Answer (score 1):

In both AWS and Google Cloud, you can do just about anything via a programming language including Python.

Last year, AWS announced EC2 Pause and Resume. This feature allows you to setup and configure an EC2 instance and when you are finished with your data processing, put the instance to sleep. You then just pay for storage and IP address costs.

[New – Hibernate Your EC2 Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-hibernate-your-ec2-instances/)

Google has also announced `alpha` features for pausing Compute Engine instances, but this feature is not generally available today - you must apply to use this feature.

Another option supported by both AWS and Google today is instance templates. This allows you to create a template with all the options that you want, such as installing packages on startup. You can then launch a new custom instance from the console, CLI or with your favorite programming language. When your task is complete you can then stop or terminate the instance.

Of course there is also the standard method. Launch an instance, configure as required and then stop the instance. When you need processing power, start the instance, data process and then stop again. The difference between this method and pausing an instance is the total time to start an instance is faster with resume. Sort of like your laptop. Close the lid and the laptop goes to sleep. Open the lid and you have almost instant-on.

If you are fortunate enough to have a running Kubernetes cluster, you can do everything with a container and launch the container via CLI. The container will automatically stop once the container finishes its task.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a script that invokes AWS CLI to start up an instance, connect to it and run the script via SSH and then terminate the instance. See AWS CLI documentation here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-ec2-launch.html.

An alternative to @bspeagle's suggestion of AWS Lambda is GCP's Cloud Functions.